# Java: Select elements from array by class-field

Tags: java, arrays, class, select

```
public class Book {
public String author;
public String title;
public int pages;
//...
}
```

I have class Book, create array `Book[] books=new Book[4];`
How to select author, that wrote the biggest amount of books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop through the array and for each unique author keep a count of the total number of books that author has published in a seperate array....... I would suggest you create a new class for author that contains their name and number of books they published and just increment it every time you add a book with their name.